# Stop QWidgets from stacking on top of each other dynamically

Tags: qt, qwidget

I create all my `QWidget`s with code and put them in a tab. However all of the widgets are stacked on top of each other. Is there a way to move widgets dynamic?. It would be possible to move the widgets dynamic to how many there already is in the widget?.
As it is know I have to move them with `move()` which could be hard to keep track on when more objects are added.

```
QTabWidget* MainWindow::CreateTabWidget(){
    QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget(ui->centralWidget);
    tabWidget->setFixedSize(this->size().width(),this->size().height()- 40);

    QWidget* tab = new QWidget();
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Sektionnamn",tab);
    QLineEdit* line = new QLineEdit(tab);
    line->move(0,20);    

    tabWidget->addTab(tab,"Tab 1");

    return tabWidget;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QLayout:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel("Sektionnamn");
QLineEdit* line = new QLineEdit();

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(label);
layout->addWidget(line);
tab->setLayout(layout);
```